# Scan internal network from cloud system?

Tags: networking, firewall, azure-networking, port-scanning, nessus

I have an internal network with bunch of devices and there is firewall at entry point from internet.

Is it possible to scan that entire internal network from the cloud server where I have tool (for exa: Nessus)? (Without installing any client software)

Or if possible with openvpn?

Comment: Which network to scan? Your cloud private network? Sure, you can. Your "on premises" network? If there's a tunnel between cloud and office, it might be possible. Cloud's network (not your)? If cloud is decent, no. What is the exact clear problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one of two things.

1. remote access to a device on the 'internal network' which can scan for you.
2. A VPN connection to the remote 'internal network' site which allocates you an IP on the same IP range as the devices you would like to scan. Yes, OpenVPN would work. Your router may or may not support OpenVPN. Realisticly - It probably doesn't.

If you're looking for the easiest way to do this and your router doesn't support openVPN (and you don't know what I mean when I say 'ddwrt') just install an old computer or RaspberryPi and allow ssh to this device.